# SASS misinterprets attr(data-something)

Tags: css, sass

I have a following situation with SASS:

```
.theme-blue > div {
  @include theme-gradient(get-badge-image("1"), #6699CC, #336699);
}

<div class="theme-blue"> <div data-badge="1">...</div> </div>
```

This should combine both referred image and gradient as one backgroudn in order to get them work properly. This works.

But if I declare:

```
.theme-blue > div {
      @include theme-gradient(get-badge-image(attr(data-badge)), #6699CC, #336699);
    }
```

I'll get an error where browser tries to fetch e.g *"badge-attr(data-badge).png"* instead of *"badge-1.png"*.

What's going wrong? If I try to access attr(data-badge) via plain CSS (like having it as a content in ::after pseudo-element), it displays "1" as expected.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501726/access-html-attribute-value-in-sass

Answer (score 1):

SASS generates CSS, the `get-badge-image()` functions cannot access your data-attribute during compilation, because there is not HTML, you're still compiling the SASS.