# Is it possible to generalize styles in CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass, less

At the moment i have styles defined as:

```
.style1 { background-image: url("../images/kitten1.jpg"); }
.style2 { background-image: url("../images/kitten2.jpg"); }
.style3 { background-image: url("../images/kitten3.jpg"); }
```

and use it in HTML as:

```
<div class="style1"></div>
<div class="style2"></div>
<div class="style3"></div>
```

I have removed the crud but in essence the styles are all the same except for the url string of the background-image. If i require many of such styles it becomes annoying if i want to make a small change to all of them.

A quick search on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501726/access-html-attribute-value-in-sass) shows it is not possible to pass arguments to CSS because it doesn't interact with HTML. However, i wonder if there is any way in which i could pass the url to only a single style, i.e.:

```
.style { background-image: url(url_string); }
```

and apply it in HTML with something like:

```
<div class="style" url_string="../images/kitten1.jpg"></div>
<div class="style" url_string="../images/kitten2.jpg"></div>
<div class="style" url_string="../images/kitten3.jpg"></div>
```

using HTML, CSS, JQuery, LESS, SASS, etc?

Comment: ofcourse css preprocessors can use variables.

Comment: @Jai - that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JayMee _using CSS, JQuery, LESS, SASS, etc?_........and this was a comment not an answer though.

Comment: @Harry - sure, i used an answer from the duplicate to solve my problem